# Jinja Flask issue: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse

Tags: flask, jinja2

Hi I've got an issue passing a simple variable from Flask app to javascript. My python looks as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
def loadInitialData():

    data={"grade":"0"}

    return render_template('index.html', data= json.dumps(data))
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{{ data }}');
console.log(data);
```

And I keep getting this error:

VM24:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse ()

Comment: Is that javascript code in the index.html template, or in a standalone .js file?

Comment: standalone .js which i reference in the html

Comment: ok, so the Jinja parsing only works on the html template and not the .js file, so your {{ data }} is not evaluated in to the JSON data from Flask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jinja variable parsing only works on the html template (passed in to `render_template`), so if your Javascript code is in a static JS file the Flask/Jinja variables can't be accessed.

Comment: ahh i see...so if I write my script directly into the html it should work..how do people work around this when they want to move their js to its own file?

Comment: Hi @kPow989, did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue and would like to move my JS code to its own file

Comment: @squeegene. .no unfortunately I ended up just moving my code to the HTML file...I don't think this is an issue in Django however..maybe give that a try if you can't find a workaround in Flask