# Fix @ Jinja variable parsing at Javascript code in a static JS file …?

Tags: javascript, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am running into this “old problem”: Jinja variable parsing only works on the html template (passed in to render_template), so if your Javascript code is in a static JS file the Flask/Jinja variables can't be accessed”.
[Jinja Flask issue: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291944/jinja-flask-issue-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position)
Does anyone know if there is already a solution for this. It's ugly to embed the JS code in the HTML file

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`tojson` Jinja filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson) to safely embed only the JSON data into the document, then load it in JS.

```
{% set data = [1, 2, 3, 4] %}
<script id="data" type="application/json">{{ data|tojson }}</script>
```

And in the external JS file:

```
const value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').textContent);
```